# SQL Join that retrieves selected record and where clause

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to retrieve two records from the database which retrieves the current department and the department in charge of it.

For example Department id 13 is Managed by department id 18

```
select dm.* from TblDepartment d 
join TblDepartment dm 
on d.ManagedBy = dm.id or d.id = dm.ManagedBy
where d.id = 13
```

which join do I need to use to retrieve the details of both the department information of department 13 and department 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the follwoing:

```
select d.id Dept_Id, d.ManagedBy 
from 
    TblDepartment d 
where
    d.id = 13
union
select dm.id Dept_Id , dm.ManagedBy
from 
    TblDepartment d 
inner 
    join TblDepartment dm 
on  d.ManagedBy = dm.id
where 
    d.id = 13
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer

Answer (score 1):

Two rows

```
select 'Dept' as [type], * from 
TblDepartment d 
where d.id = 13
union all
select ' managed by' as [type], * from 
TblDepartment d 
where d.id = 18
```

Or with a join and one input:

```
select 'Dept' as [type], * from 
TblDepartment d 
where d.id = 13
union all
select ' managed by' as [type], m.* from 
TblDepartment d 
join TblDepartment m on d.ManagedBy = m.id and d.id = 13
```